Changing the size of TransformedBbox in matplotlib
When zooming, it is done by changing xlim and ylim.
But this is very slow.
Even if xlim and ylim are changed, restore_region is based on the size of the axes, so it does not affect previously created backgrounds.
It is possible to change the xy coordinates exposed by restore_region or the created background. However, I don't know how to zoom the created background or limit the area when creating the background.
Is this possible? When creating a background for blit, limit the xlim and ylim of the bbox.
Since figure.canvas.draw() is very slow, I think I can use matplotlib more quickly if this task is possible.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from matplotlib.transforms import TransformedBbox


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
cv: FigureCanvasAgg = fig.canvas
ax: Axes

ax.plot([1, 2, 3])
bx: TransformedBbox = ax.bbox

xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()

bg = []
a = [True]
def lim(*args):
    if not bg: bg.append(cv.copy_from_bbox(bx))
    bg[0].set_x(0)
    bg[0].set_y(0)
    if a[0]:
        ax.set_xlim(0.5, 1.5)
        ax.set_ylim(1, 2.5)
        a[0] = False
    else:
        ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
        ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
        a[0] = True
    cv.draw()
    if not a[0]: cv.restore_region(bg[0])

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lim)
plt.show()


Could you add an example of what you have done and what you want to have?

add image. It's a similar task to set lim, but I'd like to know if it's also possible with Blit.
